# Whats meant by the identity function in this question?

Tags: boolean-algebra, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

It  is  generally   desirable   in  the context of  perceptron  learning    to  have    a   trainable
threshold   $s$.     Prove   that    a   one-input   neuron  with    a fixed threshold $s=−1$ could not  learn   to  carry   out the identity    function.

Assuming the input is $x$, is the identity function $x+x= x$ or $x\cdot x = x$ (or am I misunderstanding something here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the identity function referred to here is f(x) = x

Comment: does that mean that the identity function is itself (x)?

Comment: the identity function takes in some x and returns x (it just returns exactly what it took in)

Comment: so yes, I suppose you could say the identity function is itself "x". we write f(x) = x to clarify that f is a function

Comment: the truth tables for  x+x= x and x.x = x also return the same value as the input, does that mean that they are also the identity function?

Comment: sure, but that is a little confusing because at first glance, it seems like the operators +,* are functions that take in 2 variables and return 1 like so:

g(x,y) = x+y,
h(x,y) = x*y

but then you only allow the same variable for both input parameters:

g(x,x) = x+x,
h(x,x) = x*x

so, in reality, they are functions that take in 1 variable and return 1 like so:

g(x) = x+x = x,
h(x) = x*x = x

which would, indeed, end up being equivalent to the identity function. sorry for the bad formatting idk how to fix it in a comment

Comment: thank you for clarifying

Comment: np. good luck on your ml assignment